# How to access latlon coordinates after clicking on a bokeh map

Tags: python, callback, onclick, bokeh, tap

Here is the example code from the bokeh docs for 'Mapping Geo Data'

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.tile_providers import CARTODBPOSITRON

output_notebook()

# range bounds supplied in web mercator coordinates
p = figure(x_range=(-2000000, 6000000), y_range= (-1000000, 7000000), x_axis_type="mercator", y_axis_type="mercator")
p.add_tile(CARTODBPOSITRON)

show(p)
```

I would like to access the latitude and longitude coordinates after clicking on the map.

Is it possible to do that using bokeh?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What do you mean by access it, like see the lon and lat in a label or something?

Comment: Hello! I have not tried much besides copypasting code for hovertool and callbacks. would like to extract the latlons and then use the latlon-pair as input for other functions. On the fly plotting of timeseries based on the latlons coords.

Comment: Access how? In JavaScript? Or in Python? If the latter that is only possible via a Bokeh server application. The script above generates a standalone HTML page with no connection to any python runtime.